# NO GRUB in UBUNTU 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04

I have a brand new Lenovo Thinkserver TS440 with 4-2TB brand new hard drives with nothing on them, and when I try to install this OS, it loads the whole program after hitting enter several times, when it gets to the end of the install and asks for restart I get a fatal error, and it won't boot into the program.
My suspicion is there is no Grub or boot software on the disc, but not sure.....anyone?

Comment: Try changing your BIOS settings from UEFI to Legacy.

Comment: What is the output when it writes the bootloader? Maybe you are going through the wizard to fast.

Comment: Thanks for the reply albal, however I don't control the speed of the install, it loads at it's own speed from the disc, and when the it's finished the message says to remove the disc, and press enter which I did, but then it will not boot into the OS.  I have to hit esc and then enter several times and then the black screen goes into blue and then you will see Ubuntu load, but we all know this is not right or normal, it should load all by itself after the program is installed..

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks related to your BIOS setting try entering your BIOS and look for some thing named IDE STORAGE MODE or STORAGE COMPATIBILITY MODE and change that from RAID or AHCI to IDE or COMPATIBLE mode.

Comment: I will try that Vijay, but I did check in the Bios and it is set to Auto with Legacy and UEFI under that, so I'm thinking that Auto means it will use the better of the two when installing, but the fact that no boot software (Grub) is on the disc that could be the problem.